# I can't get INSERT INTO to work with php

Tags: php, sql

I really have no idea what I am doing wrong. All other queries (SELECT-queries) work without any problem, but this doesn't seem to work. Any ideas?

```
<?php
session_start();
$host="*******"; // Host name 
$username="*******"; // Mysql username 
$password="*******"; // Mysql password 
$db_name="*******"; // Database name 
$from = $_GET['from'];
$to = $_GET['to'];

// Connect to server and select databse.
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die("cannot connect"); 
mysql_select_db("$db_name",$con)or die("cannot select DB");

mysql_query("INSERT INTO message('from', 'to', 'message', 'confirm') VALUES (2,3,'would like to add you as a friend',1)");

echo'The request has been sent.';
```

Comment: try back ticks on ``message``

Comment: [**Please, don't use `mysql_*` functions in new code**](http://bit.ly/phpmsql). They are no longer maintained and the [deprecation process](http://j.mp/Rj2iVR) has begun on it. See the [**red box**](http://j.mp/Te9zIL)? Learn about [*prepared statements*](http://j.mp/T9hLWi) instead, and use [PDO](http://php.net/pdo) or [MySQLi](http://php.net/mysqli) - [this article](http://j.mp/QEx8IB) will help you decide which. If you choose PDO, [here is a good tutorial](http://j.mp/PoWehJ).

Comment: "doesnt seem to work" is not a problem description. Please provide us with the necessary details of "what does not work" and any additional clues, like error messages.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You are using reserved words from, to as your field names. Escape them with a backtick, instead of quotes.

```
      mysql_query("INSERT INTO message(`from`, `to`, `message`, `confirm`) VALUES (2,3,'would like to add you as a friend',1)");
```

See the full list of MySQL reserved words [here](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.5/en/reserved-words.html)

Answer (score 4):

You need to back-tick escape your column named 'from' and 'to' or rename the column to a non-reserved word. This is going to bite you and anyone else querying this table in the butt forever, so i lean towards rename.

```
`from`, `to`
```

Please make a promise to the gods youll never name a column or db a mysql reserved word again.

Answer (score 1):

As a rule of thumb, always use built-in function `or die(mysql_error());` at the end of your queries, this will output the actual problem  in your query in a clear text, so  do that before, you customize it. In this case, change your codes to

```
mysql_query("INSERT INTO message('from', 'to', 'message', 'confirm') VALUES (2,3,'would like to add you as a friend',1)") or die(mysql_error());
```

And these to:

```
$con = mysql_connect("$host", "$username", "$password")or die(mysql_error()); 
 mysql_select_db("$db_name",$con)or die(mysql_error());
```

You will then see what the problem is.

Answer (score 1):

Check if have unique index on some column of message.